# How to use the calc++ example provided by bison?

Tags: bison, calculator, flex-lexer

I am a freshman in using bison and flex.
I downloaded the package provided by gnu bison official site.
There is a example folder contains source codes of a calculator in C++.
Here is the download link: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/

I did following action:

> bison -d calc++-parser.yy    => OK, produce calc++-parser.tab.hh and calc++-parser.tab.cc
>
> flex calc++-scanner.ll       => OK, produce lex.yy.c
>
> cc -o a.out lex.yy.c calc++-parser.tab.cc -lfl  => failed

I have no idea why I failed in the third step, in fact, I don't really know whether I do right or not.

> calc++-scanner.ll:2:20: error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
>
> calc++-scanner.ll:5:19: error: string: No such file or directory
>
> In file included from calc++-scanner.ll:6: ../../doc/bison.texinfo:8284:16: error: map: No such file or directory
>
> In file included from ../../doc/bison.texinfo:8285, from calc++-scanner.ll:6: ../../doc/bison.texinfo:8440: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or 'attribute' before 'calcxx_driver'
>
> (... such error msg)

Compiler Version: gcc 4.2.1

Bison: 2.5.1

Flex:  2.5.4

After using {g++} instead of {cc}:

> u97530048@csie0[9:45pm]~/Compiler/calc++>g++ -o a.out lex.yy.c calc++-parser.tab.cc -lfl
>
> In file included from ../../doc/bison.texinfo:8285,from ../../doc/bison.texinfo:8504:
>
> ./calc++-parser.hh:126: error: redefinition of 'class yy::calcxx_parser'
>   calc++-parser.tab.hh:96: error: previous definition of 'class yy::calcxx_parser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with Bison 2.7.2.  Bison 2.5 is ancient, you should upgrade and report problems you might encounter them.

Comment: Thanks akim! I had upgrade it. 
I finally found a website provides Makefile for this example. (I search for it as hard as I can). I'll provide the Makefile that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> all: calc++.out
>
> calc++.out: calc++-driver.o calc++-parser.o calc++-scanner.o calc++.o
>
> g++ -o calc++.out calc++-driver.o calc++-parser.o calc++-scanner.o calc++.o
>
> calc++-driver.o: calc++-driver.cc calc++-driver.hh calc++-parser.hh
>
> g++ -c calc++-driver.cc
>
> calc++-parser.o: calc++-parser.cc calc++-parser.hh calc++-driver.hh
>
> g++ -c calc++-parser.cc
>
> calc++-parser.cc calc++-parser.hh: calc++-parser.yy
>
> bison --defines=calc++-parser.hh -ocalc++-parser.cc calc++-parser.yy
>
> calc++-scanner.o: calc++-scanner.cc calc++-parser.hh calc++-driver.hh
>
> g++ -c calc++-scanner.cc
>
> calc++-scanner.cc: calc++-scanner.ll
>
> flex -ocalc++-scanner.cc calc++-scanner.ll
>
> calc++.o: calc++.cc
>
> g++ -c calc++.cc
>
> .PHONY: clean
>
> clean:
>
> -rm *.o calc++-parser.hh calc++-parser.cc calc++-scanner.cc location.hh position.hh stack.hh calc++.out